# How to authenticate integration tests in Azure AD w/ MFA enabled?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

We have multi-factor authentication (MFA) enabled in our Azure AD.  This is perfectly fine when a user is accessing a protected resource (website).  However, it poses a problem when trying to implement a CI pipeline that includes automated integration/acceptance tests.  To get around this, we are currently using the authorization code flow to authenticate the application using an app key.

However, the web application supports role-based security with various features enabled/disabled based on the user's role.  This is easy to test manually because we can sign into the application using test accounts that are associated with the different roles.  Because we have to use the authorization code flow to circumvent MFA in our automated tests, we have no way of testing the security aspects of our application (other than requiring an authenticated user).

Is there a way to make this work so we get an access token that contains claims based on the specific role we are testing just as we would if signing in as a user?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Auth0 Authorization Extension to store tokens based on roles and permissions. https://medium.com/tojs/adding-groups-roles-and-permissions-to-a-jwt-access-token-in-auth0-827cc7df7662

My suggestion would be to use one token, and track somewhere a relation between USER and TOKEN_VALID_IF_ISSUED_AFTER.

At that point, when a user logs out, when their permissions change, when they change password you can insert a record in this table with $USER_ID and NOW().

Next time a token goes through your API you validate that it was issued after the TOKEN_VALID_IF_ISSUED_AFTER through the iat claim -- if not, the user will have to get a brand new token.

See also this thread that provides a workaround: [Role based tokens ASP.net Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071137/role-based-tokens-asp-net-identity)